# SQL Query Search page

Tags: php, wp-query, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a Wordpress webpage that has an input text box and a button. what I want to do is take the input text from the text box and use it as a parameter to search a table I put into the website database and print the results on the screen. I tried using PHP to no avail. what is the best to do this?
here is the code

```
Search the Film Database <input id="input" name="input" type="text" /> [php] global $wpdb; echo '<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>'; $text = sanitize_text_field($_POST['input']); echo $text; $wpdb->query('USE vcuw2938212664'); function myFunction(){ $txt = sanitize_text_field($_POST['input']); echo 'text is "$txt; $query = 'SELECT * FROM documentaries WHERE English_Title = \'%Li%\';'; echo $query; $results = $wpdb->get_results($query); if ($results != Null){ echo "{$results}"; } else { echo 'no results returned'; } } [/php]
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried in your question please?

Comment: sure! here is my code!

Comment: Search the Film Database
<input id="input" name="input" type="text" />
[php]
global $wpdb;
echo '<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>';
$text = sanitize_text_field($_POST['input']);
echo $text;
$wpdb->query('USE vcuw2938212664');
function myFunction(){
$txt = sanitize_text_field($_POST['input']);
echo 'text is "$txt;
$query = 'SELECT \* FROM documentaries WHERE English_Title = \'%Li%\';';
echo $query;
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
if ($results != Null){
echo "{$results}";
}
else {
echo 'no results returned';
}
}
[/php]

Comment: Please put the code in your question and format it.

Comment: You shouldn't be using plugins that embed PHP code in `[php]` shortcodes, they're a major security risk

Answer (score 0):

you can use `WP_Query();` to query the results.

it has an argument `'s' => $search_query`,

create an input, get the input value, store it in `$search_query`, then create a query,

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 's' => $search_query ) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
     while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

     // do something...

     endwhile;
     wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Comment: i use ajax to create custom search forms for advance property search you can see an example here : http://216.120.250.9/~kathleenkellett/local-info/businesses/

Comment: I know that I want to search a table named "documentaries" that I already inputted and and to find row where the the column "English_Title" has the input String in it. How do I do that?

Comment: by the way, I am having a problem looking for a way to get a button to run it!

Comment: the table name is "documentaries" ? what are you creating?

Comment: I am creating a database SQL search engine to search the table "documentaries" based on a user inputted string from the input called "input" and prints the results of that search to the screen

Comment: instead of creating a new table with the name `documentaries` why dont you save your records in `wp_posts` table with `post_type' as `documentaries` this way you will be able to create, edit, delete posts from backend, also all the query codes will work perfect.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: you can do it by registering `documentaries` `custom post type` please read more here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: @Justintadlock has explained very clearly over here http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress. you can also generate custom post type code here https://generatewp.com/post-type/